# Detect browser support for cross-domain XMLHttpRequests?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm working on some Javascript that makes use of Firefox 3.5's ability to perform cross-domain XMLHttpRequests… But I'd like to fail gracefully if they aren't supported.

Apart from actually making a cross-domain request, is there any way to detect a browser's support for them?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

For future reference, full CORS feature detection should look something like this:

```
//Detect browser support for CORS
if ('withCredentials' in new XMLHttpRequest()) {
    /* supports cross-domain requests */
    document.write("CORS supported (XHR)");
}
else if(typeof XDomainRequest !== "undefined"){
  //Use IE-specific "CORS" code with XDR
  document.write("CORS supported (XDR)");
}else{
  //Time to retreat with a fallback or polyfill
  document.write("No CORS Support!");
}
```

You can [try this test live using JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ohugih/8/edit) and see the proper response in IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera.

There are some edge cases in non-browser environments that *do support* cross-domain XHR but not XHR2/CORS. This test does not account for those situations.

Comment: You should mention, that XDomainRequest only supports GET and POST requests. If the server relies on PUT or DELETE as well, XDomainRequest will fail.

Comment: XDR also does support not cross-domain requests from `http` to `https`. See [XDomainRequest - Restrictions, Limitations and Workarounds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx)

Comment: note, ie11 gives false positives, as it does not support CORS with cached images http://web.onassar.com/blog/2013/11/07/internet-explorer-11-and-cors-crossorigin-support/

Answer (score 35):

According to http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/ you should be able to use:

```
if ('withCredentials' in new XMLHttpRequest()) {
    /* supports cross-domain requests */
}
```

(Note: there is a comment on that page that Chrome 2 fails this test [although it does support cross-domain requests]. I tested Chrome 3 and the test is now passing.)

Keep in mind that just because the browser might support the [cross-domain API](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control) does not mean the target server will allow the request to complete.

Comment: I tried this but I get a false positive on Opera. My specific case is actually loading a local file from a local file, that can be activated by checking a security preference... however I can't tell whether this preference is actually checked or not without trying.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at [EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/), which wraps cross-browser quirks and provides an easy-to-use API for communicating in client script between different domains using the best available mechanism for that browser (e.g. [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) if available, other mechanisms if not).

Clearly that library has solved the browser-capabilities detection problem, so you can benefit from their experience. :-)

Answer (score 1):

IE8 also has [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28VS.85%29.aspx) object that can be used to retrieve RSS as text which can later be parsed into DOM.