# Unable POST to my API with AJAX & jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, api

I am new to jQuery and javascript and am really having a hard time to POST and GET to my API. I am able to POST fine when I did a curl request over git bash command line but can't do it over JS and jQuery. It also is unable to populate on my main HTML page. Below is the code I have for my form:

```
<h2>My Lists:</h2>
<ul id="orders"></ul>

<h3>Add Restaurant</h3>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <p>
        restaurant name: 
        <input type="text" id="name">
    </p>
    <input id="add-rest" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>         
<script src="jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

```js
$(function(){
    var $orders = $('#orders');
    var $name = $('#name');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://testing-sh1.appspot.com/restaurant',
        success: function(orders){
            $.each(orders, function(i, order){
                $orders.append('<li>name: ' + order.name + '</li>');
            });
        }
    });
});

$('#add-rest').on('submit', function(){
    var order = {
        name: $name.val(),
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://testing-sh1.appspot.com/restaurant',
        data: order,
        success: function(newOrder){
            $orders.append('<li>name: ' + newOrder.name + '</li>');
        }
    });
});
```

I have my live API URL there just for testing. Hopefully a second set of eyes can help me out. Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: check your browser console to check if there is any error...

Comment: Have you setup CORS on your API? If not your request is probably being stopped by the Same Origin Policy. Check the console for errors.

Comment: How do I check if CORS is set up? and if its not, how do I go about setting it up?

Comment: You can check the headers of a request. Although from your response I'm guessing it hasn't. To add CORS headers would depend on what language the API uses.

Comment: I believe I have it set up. I'm using python on Google App Engine.  self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST")
         self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept")
  self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
         self.response.headers.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

Comment: Also note that the URL you're using returns no data, just two properties with empty arrays.

Comment: There are only two arrays (names and keys ) are there in json .. I think CORS might not be the issue , it has something to do with API 's request handling , but if its CORS , In google chrome you can install a plugin named "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin" and turn it on while doing requests .

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, in

```
var order = {
    name: $name.val(),
};
```

Remove the tailing `,` to make it a valid object.

I got this response with 'test'

```
{"reviews": [], "name": "test", "key": 5649391675244544}
```

I tested the AJAX directly.

Also make sure that the variables are passed correctly and that they are defined in their respective function's scope. Like with your current code, `var $name = $('#name');` `$name` won't be accessible in your submit's handler since it's local to another function with a different scope.

You'll also need to prevent the default behavior of form submit since you are handling the event via a custom AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I was wondering if you hardcoded the order or did you use the html form. I tried with the form with the edits you suggested, and I'm still coming up with nothing.

Comment: I'll update the answer for you for more hints on where you can look for issues.

Answer (score 0):

**You have an Error in your server**
Im just make a API call

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Internal Server Error</title>
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 20px;
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      pre {
        background: #F2F2F2;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
    <p>The server has either erred or is incapable of performing
    the requested operation.</p>
    <pre>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py&quot;, line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py&quot;, line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py&quot;, line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py&quot;, line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py&quot;, line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py&quot;, line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File &quot;/base/data/home/apps/s~testing-sh1/1.391270213179374270/restaurant.py&quot;, line 29, in post
    key = new_restaurant.put()
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py&quot;, line 3451, in _put
    return self._put_async(**ctx_options).get_result()
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py&quot;, line 342, in get_result
    self.check_success()
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py&quot;, line 386, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py&quot;, line 824, in put
    key = yield self._put_batcher.add(entity, options)
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py&quot;, line 389, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.send(val)
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py&quot;, line 358, in _put_tasklet
    keys = yield self._conn.async_put(options, datastore_entities)
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py&quot;, line 1852, in async_put
    pbs = [entity_to_pb(entity) for entity in entities]
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py&quot;, line 697, in entity_to_pb
    pb = ent._to_pb()
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py&quot;, line 3158, in _to_pb
    self._check_initialized()
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py&quot;, line 3014, in _check_initialized
    'Entity has uninitialized properties: %s' % ', '.join(baddies))
BadValueError: Entity has uninitialized properties: name
</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now Im send a name, and response is

```
{
"reviews": [0]
"name": "testing"
"key": 5722646637445120
}
```

You need to change this part from your ajax call`

```
var order = $name.val();


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://testing-sh1.appspot.com/restaurant',
        data: {name:order},
        success: function(newOrder){
            $orders.append('<li>name: ' + newOrder.name + '</li>');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The response you are getting is in string, change it to an object and also when using ajax try to avoid form
And also declare global variables outside function

<h2>My Lists:</h2>
<ul id="orders"></ul>
<h3>Add Restaurant</h3>
<div>
    <p>
        restaurant name: 
        <input type="text" id="name">
    </p>
    <input id="add-rest" type="submit" value="submit">
</div>         
<script type="text/javascript" src="../myspace/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script> 

        var $orders = $('#orders');
        var $name = $('#name');
        $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://testing-sh1.appspot.com/restaurant',
                success: function(orders){
                    orders = JSON.parse(orders);
                    for (var key in orders) {
                        var obj = orders[key];
                       for (var prop in obj) {
                          //do your append code here
                        }
                    }
                    /*$.each(orders, function(i, order){
                        $orders.append('<li>name: ' + order.name + '</li>');
                    });*/
                }
            });
        });

        $('#add-rest').on('click', function(){
            var order = {
                name: $name.val(),
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://testing-sh1.appspot.com/restaurant',
                data: order,
                success: function(newOrder){
                    newOrder = JSON.parse(newOrder);
                    $orders.append('<li>name: ' + newOrder.name +', password: '+ newOrder.password + '</li>');
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought on CORS, you can check with this post, but most of the time you already know because you had to set up the server to support:
[Detect browser support for cross-domain XMLHttpRequests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641507/detect-browser-support-for-cross-domain-xmlhttprequests)
Did you set up the server?